# Python crypt.crypt not using sha512 despite $6$

Tags: python, python-3.x, crypt, sha512

For some reason using the `crypt` module uses the `13` char hash rather than `sha-512` no matter what I try. I have seen countless questions about problems, but none of them match mine. Is there simply no way to change the crypt method?

```
>>> import crypt
>>> print(crypt.crypt("password", salt="$6$saltsalt"))
$6FMi11BJFsAc
>>> print(crypt.crypt("password", crypt.METHOD_SHA512))
$6FMi11BJFsAc
>>>
```

Not sure exactly what is going on. If this is a case-specific thing, are there alternatives to crypt that have the same `crypt(3)` functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  You need at least Python 3.3 to get an implementation that understands the `$6$...` format to select different hashing algorithms.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.5 on mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, an  [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue33213) with the crypt(3) implementation on Macs. There is a cross-platform crypt library, [passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but it doesn't seem to have received any updates in over a year; still, it's one Ansible recommends in it's [FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module), for example.